# Validate text boxes so values must be entered

Tags: javascript, validation

Hi I am trying to get this code to validate text boxes so they must contain a value; if they dont I want a message to appear explaining that the fields cannot be blank. Here is the code I have written:

```
<head>
<title>Exam entry</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {
    var result = true;
    var msg="";

        if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
        msg+="You must enter your name \n";
        document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
        document.gotElementById('name').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

        if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
        msg+="You must enter the subject \n";
        document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
        document.gotElementById('subject').style.color="red";
        result = false;
    }

        if (document.ExamEntry.examno.value=="") {
        msg+="You must enter an examination number \n";
        document.ExamEntry.examno.focus();
        document.gotElementById('examno').style.color="red";
        result = false;

    if(msg==""){
    return result;
    }

    {
    alert(msg)
    return result;
    }
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
<table width="50%" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="name">Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="subject">Subject</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="examno">Examination Number</td>
        <td><input type="integer" name="examno" /></td>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validationFrom();" /></td>
    <td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Any help would be great thanks

Comment: You are missing a } at the end of third if. Also, there is a lot of code duplication, try do abstract it in a function.

Answer (score 2):

1. getElementById and not gotelementById
2. use fullName instead of the reserved word name
3. do not use the same IDs as the form names - IE will be confused
4. do NOT use submit button's onclick. Instead use form onsubmit
5. you will likely not be allowed to POST to a HTML file
6. HTML5 supports type="number" not "integer"
7. add the attribute `value` to each field

Here is my suggestion - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/r7k7Z/)

I have changed the label IDs and changed name to fullName

```
function setError(fld,id,msg) {

   if (fld.value=="") {
     document.getElementById(id).className="error";
     return msg;
   }
   document.getElementById(id).className="normal";
   return "";

}
window.onload=function() {
  document.getElementById("ExamEntry").onsubmit=function() {

    var msg,msgs=[],focusField="";
    msg=setError(this.fullName,"fullNameLabel","You must enter your name");
    if (msg) { msgs.push(msg); focusField = this.fullName;}
    msg=setError(this.subject,"subjectLabel","You must enter the subject");
    if (msg) {  msgs.push(msg); focusField = focusField || this.subject;}

    var examno = this.examno;
    msg = setError(examno,"examnoLabel","You must enter an examination number");
    if (msg) { msgs.push(msg); focusField = focusField || examno;}
    else {
      if (isNaN( examno.value) ||  examno.value.length<4) {
        msgs.push("You must enter a valid examination number");
        document.getElementById("examnoLabel").className="error"
        focusField = focusField || this.examno;
      }
    }
    if(focusField) {
      alert(msgs.join("\n"));
      focusField.focus();
      return false;
    }
    return true; // allow submission
  }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic thanks, as you can tell I am a newbie! I can see now where I've gone wrong, really appreciate the help!

Comment: If I were to extend the Examination number field to validate that the exam number is at least 4 numbers in length how would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to run into problems if you name your input elements with reserved words, like `name`. The code:

```
document.ExamEntry.name.value
```

Will cause you problems, because the `ExamEntry` form already has an property called `name`. You should either rename your field, or use:

```
document.ExamEntry.elements['name'].value
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute value is not directly available with the elements, you should always use:

```
element.getAttribute('value')
```

this will get you the value attribute.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Huh? How do you get to that conclusion?